# Boundedness of the solution of the heat equation

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

The general solution of the heat equation
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\partial_tu-\Delta u &=& 0\\
u(x,0)&=& f
\end{array} \right.$$
is given by $$u(x,t)=\int\limits_{\mathbb R^n}\Phi(x-y,t)f(y)\mathrm dy$$
with the fundamental solution $\Phi$ ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Fundamental_solutions)).

So why is the solution $u\in C^0([0,\infty)\times\mathbb R^n)\cap C^\infty((0,\infty)\times\mathbb R^n)$ bounded if f is bounded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental solution is positive, integrable on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(x,t)\,dx=1$ for all $t>0$. Then
$$
|u(x,t)|\le\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(x-y,t)|f(y)|\,dy\le\sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}^n}|f(y)|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(x-y,t)\,dy=\sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}^n}|f(y)|<\infty.
$$